# Open source document classes similar to Cam. Ser. Stat. & Prob. Math. journal style?

Tags: document-classes, styles

I quite like the style file used in the Cambridge Series in Statistical and Probabilistic Mathematics.

There are some key features of this style:

- Times New Roman used throughout; tailored environments like proof environments use slightly different bold face/spacing conventions.
- Theorem/Lemma/Propositions are under grey boxes; they're simply outlined.
- Different greek letters used that play well with times new roman.
- Italicized short titles at the top of each chapter page, left right page numbering.

My question is: do you know of any similar open source class definitions? I'd like to not have to start completely from scratch.

Here is a screenshot of part of a book in 
this series: 
[image]

Comment: Need to be a class? A code with `memoir` and definitions about this elements can be pursued...